# How to convert my GML/KML/SHP files into deegree workspace?

Tags: gml, deegree

I am newbie in geographic and want to convert my GML file to [deegree](http://www.deegree.org) workspace.

What I did so far

1. I have download deegree and install it on local.
2. Run the application and its [service](http://download.deegree.org/documentation/3.2.1/html/lightly.html#example-workspace-1-inspire-network-services)

Now, I want to convert my GML/KML/SHP files to Deegree workspace.

Please help me or any suggestion what i do.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use KML directly and have to import it into a DB or convert it to a shape file.

For GML and SHP you'll have to configure an appropriate FeatureStore:

GML: http://download.deegree.org/documentation/3.3.19/html/featurestores.html#memory-feature-store for starters, if you know what application schema you're using you can also set up an SQL feature store: http://download.deegree.org/documentation/3.3.19/html/featurestores.html#sql-feature-store and then upload your GML via WFS-T (this is an advanced topic).

SHP: Either setup a ShapeFeatureStore: http://download.deegree.org/documentation/3.3.19/html/featurestores.html#shape-feature-store or import the SHP with another tool like https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#shp2pgsql_usage